# wordpress rewrite rules and mod_tile (renderd) on the same domain

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I have a wordpress site and renderd running on the same domain.
I have configured renderd and mod_tile.
When I run

```
curl localhost/hot/3/4/3.png
```

from inside the server, it works.
To prevent Wordpress from the serving the page, I added the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hot/.*$`  line to the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hot/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Wordpress stopped serving the page. However, apache2 still does not serve it, returning a 404

Answer (score 0):

I added both
`LoadModule tile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so`
and mod_tile config

```
LoadTileConfigFile /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
ModTileRenderdSocketName /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
# Timeout before giving up for a tile to be rendered
ModTileRequestTimeout 0
# Timeout before giving up for a tile to be rendered that is otherwise missing
ModTileMissingRequestTimeout 30
```

to /etc/apache2/vhosts/www-root/{my-domain} file and it works now.